# Android - Navigation stack issue with bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, menuitem, bottomnavigationview

I have an activity with two fragments "Home" and "Dashboard".
There is a bottom navigation bar, providing two items "Home" and "Dashboar" to navigate to each fragment.

[image][image]

A third fragment, called "Subdashboard" could be called with a button inside the fragment "Dashboard".

Code of MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
}
```

Snippet of my button in "DashboardFragment" to navigate to SubDashboardFragment

```
        val mybutton: Button = binding.mybutton
        mybutton.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_navigate_to_subdashboard)
        }
```

My goal : When I am on the Subdashboard fragment, i want to come back to Dashboard Fragment, either by clicking on "Dashboard" item in the menu, either by clicking on the back button on the phone.

I have the following menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_dashboard" />
</menu>
```

**Configuration A**

I have the following navigation.xml (**with "popUpToInclusive"**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="com.example.myapp.HomeFragment"
        android:label="Home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:name="com.example.myapp.DashboardFragment"
        android:label="Dashboard"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigate_to_subdashboard"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_subdashboard"
            app:popUpTo="@id/navigation_dashboard"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"
            />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_subdashboard"
        android:name="com.example.myapp.SubdasboardFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_subdashboard"
        android:label="Subdashboard"/>

</navigation>
```

**Test 1 :** When i click on "Dashboard" item, navigation to Dashboard is OK. I click on the button "Go to subdashboard", navigation to Subdashboard is OK.
If i click again on the "Dashboard" item in the menu, it's OK, i'm going back to Dashboard Fragment. Behavior is OK.

**Test 2 :** When i click on "Dashboard" item, navigation to Dashboard is OK. I click on the button "Go to subdashboard", navigation to Subdashboard is OK.
If i click on the Back button of the phone, i'm going back **directly to Home Fragment** (so the start destination). Behavior is not OK

**Configuration B**

I have the following navigation.xml (**without "popUpToInclusive"**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="com.example.myapp.HomeFragment"
        android:label="Home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:name="com.example.myapp.DashboardFragment"
        android:label="Dashboard"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigate_to_subdashboard"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_subdashboard"
            app:popUpTo="@id/navigation_dashboard"
            />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_subdashboard"
        android:name="com.example.myapp.SubdasboardFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_subdashboard"
        android:label="Subdashboard"/>

</navigation>
```

**Test 3 :** When i click on "Dashboard" item, navigation to Dashboard is OK. I click on the button "Go to subdashboard", navigation to Subdashboard is OK.
If i click again on the "Dashboard" item in the menu, i stay stuck on the Subdashboard fragment. Behavior is not OK.

**Test 4 :** When i click on "Dashboard" item, navigation to Dashboard is OK. I click on the button "Go to subdashboard", navigation to Subdashboard is OK.
If i click on the Back button of the phone, i'm going back to Dashboard Fragment, and if i click again on back, i'm going back to Home. Behavior is OK.

Any ideas to resolve this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: May be you can override the onBackPress function and redirect to Dashboard instead of Home when back button is pressed